# How to update Real-time graph from textfile?

Tags: php, html, ajax, solaris

I intend to display a real-time graph on.php/html from a text file without refreshing the page. Currently, I got a problem in the following process.

The source file: .txt files containing the data, originating from a solaris server.

1) Periodically ask the server for data, from a solaris server. (assuming the destination folder is specified as /home/sadm/htdocs/00000001/updateShop)

2) Retrieve the data from the text file (inventory.txt)

3) Parse the data to add new rows
   eg. from (2008-1-6:33322:39463) in the text file to

> [new Date(2008, 1 ,6), 33322, undefined, undefined, 39463, undefined,
>   undefined]

If im not wrong, it would require me to use AJAX to do it, but I could not get it to work. May I ask to code the 3-steps process?

Any form of help is greatly appreciated.

The google graph API code I use is displayed below for reference.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
      google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['annotatedtimeline']});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Sold Pencils');
        data.addColumn('string', 'title1');
        data.addColumn('string', 'text1');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Sold Pens');
        data.addColumn('string', 'title2');
        data.addColumn('string', 'text2');
        data.addRows([
          [new Date(2008, 1 ,1), 30000, undefined, undefined, 40645, undefined, undefined],
          [new Date(2008, 1 ,2), 14045, undefined, undefined, 20374, undefined, undefined],
          [new Date(2008, 1 ,3), 55022, undefined, undefined, 50766, undefined, undefined],
          [new Date(2008, 1 ,4), 75284, undefined, undefined, 14334, 'Out of Stock','Ran out of stock on pens at 4pm'],
          [new Date(2008, 1 ,5), 41476, 'Bought Pens','Bought 200k pens', 66467, undefined, undefined],
          [new Date(2008, 1 ,6), 33322, undefined, undefined, 39463, undefined, undefined]
        ]);

        var chart = new google.visualization.AnnotatedTimeLine(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, {displayAnnotations: true});
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    // Note how you must specify the size of the container element explicitly!
    <div id='chart_div' style='width: 700px; height: 240px;'></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right, you need to use ajax to update the page without refreshing - you probably want to use a library such as jquery or prototype.js to make the ajax handling a bit easier. You need to set up a timed event that fires at some defined frequency (also quite easy using a library) Then you make a php script that gives you back the data you want. Depending on the update frequency of the data set and how often your timed event fires, you may run into two problem:
You call out for data,  but there are no new data, probably you do not want to have the same row twice, or
You call out for data and there are two (or more) new rows, I would guess you want all of them.

And remember, even though the X in ajax initially means xml, it is usually easier to use another format for the transfer, json or even plain text.

Hope this gives you some pointers where to proceed. (It often makes sense to start with the backend server (well, at least, I often do...), if you call it with get-parameters you can easily test it in a browser to see that you get back what you expected)